# Using Sweet alert with Typescript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have a method inside a typescript class that just looks like this

```
    var confirmation = confirm("Run Agent Job?");
    if (confirmation) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
```

I'm trying to convert this to use Sweet Alert, so inside the method I just put this. But Typescript doesn't recognize this It throws a `Cannot find name swal`

```
swal("hello");
```

I have imported sweet alert as follows

```
<link href="~/Content/css/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? If I try to use `swal()` in just a plain `*.js` file, it'll work fine. It's only when it's in a `*.ts` file.

Comment: You need to get the [type definitions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sweetalert.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) so that the TypeScript compiler will recognize it.

Comment: @MikeC  just installed them but still won't recognize it

Comment: @Jimenemex did you fixed it?

Comment: @ZackKaytranada No I wasn't able to fix it

Answer (score 7):

#### Typescript

I got it to work with typescript the following way. In the top of your `.ts` file use:

```
import * as swal from 'sweetalert';
```

Then use the function like this

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to undo this action",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  closeOnConfirm: true
},
confirmed => {
   if(confirmed) {
       // Do what ever when the user click on the 'Yes, delete it' button
   }
});
```

You can find more examples in the [docs](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

#### Installation via npm and typings

I installed the `sweetalert` package the via npm

```
npm install sweetalert --save
```

and the typings

```
// the old way
typings install dt~sweetalert --save --global 

// new way
npm install --save @types/sweetalert
```

After this, make sure you have included the js **and** the css file in your index.html.

If you get the following error

```
swal(..) is not a function
```

then you have not included the js file properly.

#### For aurelia CLI users

You can add the following to your `aurelia.json`.

```
      {
        "name": "sweetalert",
        "path": "../node_modules/sweetalert",
        "main": "dist/sweetalert.min",
        "resources": [
          "dist/sweetalert.css"
        ]
      },
```

and in app.html use

```
<require from="sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css"></require>
```

Comment: The resources part in aurelia.json configures the CLI to put it in the bundle via requirejs's text plugin, but it is not automatically loaded as valid CSS at runtime. To use it with Aurelia-CLI's build-in loading mechanism, you need to require it in an Aurelia HTML template (probably app.html). In your example adding `<require from="sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css"></require>` should work fine. Of course you cannot not require it in index.html, since it is loaded before the framework's boostrapping process and requirejs is also not loaded yet.

Comment: Note that `npm install --save @types/sweetalert` is no longer necessary because sweetalert now provides its own type definitions.

Comment: I tried as described in first part: 
1) TS file: `import swal from 'sweetalert'; swall("Hello");`
2). JS file: almost the same: `import ....`
3). index.html: `<script src="./node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`
But then when I start this page, I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "sweetalert". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

If I manually delete import from js file, it works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

We can't use the function `swal({...})` but we can use the second overload of `Swal.fire({...})` method, casting the parameters to SweetAlertOptions...
My code looks like this...

```
import Swal, {SweetAlertOptions} from 'sweetalert2';
Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'You won\'t be able to revert this!',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
      } as SweetAlertOptions).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
           //Do something here
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition `@TomAalbers` answer, there is a bug with Angular 5 and sweetalert which will also cause this error. If you are using angular 5, then you can't use:

```
import * as swal from 'sweetalert';
```

Instead you need this ugly work around:

```
import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';
const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;
```

[Credit where it's due](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/799)

> This seems to be related to this bug in Angular CLI where default exports are handled differently in dev. They seem to have fixed it in v6.0.0-beta.4

Answer (score 0):

You have to import this in top of your class:

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss'
```

and  don´t forget to add this in your app.module.ts file

[image]

Comment: It's better to paste the code as text instead of an image. Images could be lost if some is coming here after years

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript**

In this way working for me, I am using angular 7 and sweetalert2.

> Installation

- `npm install sweetalert2`

OR

- `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>`

**.ts**

```
   openDateDialog() {
    swal({
      html: '<h1>Sweet2 with angularJS</h1>',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      customClass: 'swal2-overflow'
    }).then(function(isConfirm){ if (isConfirm) {
      console.log('confirm, do any function');
    } else {
      swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }});
  }
```

**.html**

```
<mat-select [(value)]="dateselected" (selectionChange)="onChangeDate(dateselected)">
            <mat-option value="0" (click)="openDateDialog()" >Sur-Mesure</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="thisMonth" >Ce mois-ci</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="all" >Toute la période</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
```