# Sweet Alert On Ionic 4, Output Alert Inside Typescript File

Tags: ionic4, sweetalert

i am developing a forgot password process, the forgot password process are as below

1. user key in email to reset password,
2. upon user click on submit, a process will be send to server side for backend processing (in this case i make PHP as backend, MySQL is used as database),
3. upon email have been successfully submitted, a sweet alert popup will appear telling user that the email was sent successfully

the process that i want to be happened that i am unable to do so is ***Sweet Alert to appear only after email has been successfuly send, the process happen after a certain value is received on .ts file***

below are my code at **forget-password.page.html**

```
// CODE NO 1 
<button (click)="confirmSentForgotPassword()" style="letter-spacing: 1px" button margin-top>
      SUBMIT
</button>

// CODE NO 2
//<button [swal]="submit" style="letter-spacing: 1px" button margin-top>
//     SUBMIT
//</button>

<swal
        #submit
        title="Check Your Email"
        text="An email has been sent to that address containing a link to reset your password."
        type="success"
        (confirm)="dismiss()">
</swal>
```

if i use code no 2, i am able to output swal on button submit but i dont want to do this because i want swal to appear upon emel have been successfully submitted,

below are my code at **forget-password.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SweetAlert2Module } from '@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2';
import { PostProvider } from 'src/providers/post-provider';

import {
  LoadingController,
  ToastController
} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forget-password',
  templateUrl: './forget-password.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forget-password.page.scss'],
})
export class ForgetPasswordPage implements OnInit {

  email: string = null;

  constructor(
    private modalCtrl: ModalController, 
    public swal: SweetAlert2Module,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private postPvdr: PostProvider,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async dismiss() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  async confirmSentForgotPassword() {

    let body = {
      action: 'emel-forgot-password',
      email: this.email
    };

    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading...'
    });
    await loading.present();

    this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'forgotpassword-api.php').subscribe(async data2 =>{
        loading.dismiss();

        // CODE ALERT 
        // this.swal({
        //   title: "Check Your Email",
        //   text: "An email has been sent to that address containing a link to reset your password.",
        //   type: "success",
        //   showCancelButton: true,
        //   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        //   closeOnConfirm: true
        // },
        // confirmed => {
        //    if(confirmed) {
        //        this.dismiss();
        //    }
        // });

        const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: data2.msg,
          duration: 2000
        });

        toast.present();

    },async err=>{
      loading.dismiss();

      console.log(err);

      const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "Error On Server Side ",
        duration: 2000
      });

      toast.present();

    });

  }

}
```

i have tried using below reference

[Using Sweet alert with Typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958932/using-sweet-alert-with-typescript-class)

but when the swal is used the error below come out on my VSCode

```
This expression is not callable. Type 'SweetAlert2Module' has no call signatures.
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to integrate sweet alert in your project
..npm install sweetalert2

**..forget-password.ts**

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forget-password',
  templateUrl: './forget-password.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forget-password.page.scss'],
})
export class ForgetPasswordPage implements OnInit {

  email: string = null;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
   
confirmSentForgotPassword(){
Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Your work has been saved',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
});
  
}
```

}

**forgot-password.page.html**

```
<button (click)="confirmSentForgotPassword()" style="letter-spacing: 1px" button margin-top>
      SUBMIT
</button>
```

check this link for more examples [https://sweetalert2.github.io](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)